# sql query return values for rows n times

Tags: mysql, sql

**background:**

I'm generating sql queries via php for use on a wordpress database.

**problem:**

Sometimes I need 2 or more sets (rows) of the same information.

**question:**

Using my example query and with my current sql setup I'm only able to return one set of information even though I'm wanting to get 2 sets. How can I accomplish my desired result using sql?

**example query:** *generated with php*

```
SELECT suborgs.meta_value 
FROM (
  SELECT suborgs2.* 
  FROM wp_postmeta suborgs2 
  WHERE suborgs2.meta_key = 'product_relationship'
) suborgs 
WHERE  suborgs.post_id = '152' 
OR suborgs.post_id = '152';
```

*result:*

```
+-----------------------------------+
|            meta_value             |
+-----------------------------------+
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
+-----------------------------------+
```

*desired result:*

```
+-----------------------------------+
|            meta_value             |
+-----------------------------------+
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Note: This is the desired result for my example query. The query could have 9+ references to the same `suborgs.post_id` in which case I would 9+ rows in my result.** To iterate this I've created a second example with results below.

**example query 2:**

```
SELECT suborgs.meta_value 
FROM (
  SELECT suborgs2.* 
  FROM wp_postmeta suborgs2 
  WHERE suborgs2.meta_key = 'product_relationship'
) suborgs 
WHERE  suborgs.post_id = '152' 
OR suborgs.post_id = '162'
OR suborgs.post_id = '156'
OR suborgs.post_id = '152'
OR suborgs.post_id = '154'
OR suborgs.post_id = '152'
OR suborgs.post_id = '162';
```

*result:*

```
+-----------------------------------+
|            meta_value             |
+-----------------------------------+
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"31";i:1;s:3:"923";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"63";i:1;s:3:"423";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"61";i:1;s:3:"132";} |
+-----------------------------------+
```

*desired result:*

```
+-----------------------------------+
|            meta_value             |
+-----------------------------------+
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"31";i:1;s:3:"923";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"63";i:1;s:3:"423";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"61";i:1;s:3:"132";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"42";i:1;s:3:"199";} |
| a:2:{i:0;s:2:"31";i:1;s:3:"923";} |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: This has to do with user registrations in my application so if the user is registered to the same group twice then I need to pull the data for that group twice.

Comment: Can you post some data sample of your tables? you could use some [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6)

Comment: Why duplicate validation in the `where` ? `WHERE  suborgs.post_id = '152' 
OR suborgs.post_id = '152';`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think (but can't be sure) that it was the attempt to duplicate the output ;)

Comment: Originally I was only concerned with different IDs so my current implementation worked. Now I need to make sure any duplicates are accounted for as well.

Comment: Try this: `(SELECT suborgs.meta_value FROM ...) UNION ALL (SELECT suborgs.meta_value FROM ...)`

Comment: @Jackson some sample data will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery instead of `IN`:

```
SELECT suborgs.* 
FROM wp_postmeta suborgs JOIN
     (SELECT '152' as post_id UNION ALL SELECT '162' UNION ALL SELECT '156' UNION ALL
      SELECT '154' UNION ALL SELECT '152' UNION ALL SELECT '162'
     ) p
     ON suborgs.meta_key = 'product_relationship' AND
        suborgs.post_id = p.post_id;
```

Then the `JOIN` does the work for you.

Comment: Gordon, you are part of the glue that keeps SOF together. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but not pretty option, is to add a "dummy" subquery to duplicate the output:

```
SELECT suborgs.meta_value 
FROM (
  SELECT suborgs2.* 
  FROM wp_postmeta suborgs2 
  WHERE suborgs2.meta_key = 'product_relationship'
) suborgs, (select 1 union select 2) as dummy
WHERE  suborgs.post_id = '152'
```